# Confusion with Javascript variable scoping

Tags: javascript, html, scope

I'm trying to create a simple test in JS. I have a function that creates 4 radio-buttons and add them to the html. When I call it `n` times, I just add the same 4 radio buttons to the `div` and when I try to select one answer from the 4th question for example it still selects the answer from the first div/question.

```js
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function test_2() {

  var a = getRandom(0, 10) - 5;

  while (a == 0)
    a = getRandom(0, 10) - 5;

  var b = getRandom(0, 10) - 5;

  //create the div in which i add the radio buttons
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'parent');
  div.setAttribute('id', '2');

  document.body.appendChild(div);

  //create the radio button and set its attributes
  var radio1 = document.createElement('input');
  var label1 = document.createElement('label');
  label1.innerHTML = a * 4 + b;
  label1.setAttribute('for', 'radio1');
  radio1.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
  radio1.setAttribute('value', a * 4 + b);
  radio1.setAttribute('id', 'radio1');
  radio1.setAttribute('name', 'answ');
  radio1.innerHTML = a * 4 + b;

  //add it to the div
  div.appendChild(radio1);
  div.appendChild(label1);
}

test_2();
```

Comment: Please simplify the code example only to contain the relevant parts for the question.

Comment: All your `div` and again with your `input[type=radio]` elements are being given identical `id` values. `id`s must be unique within a document.

Comment: @YotamSalmon The code does not need to be simplified. There is nothing excessive here. To the contrary, more of the relevant code should be added so we can recreate the scenario.

Comment: There isn't enough code to be sure, but I suspect that the problem is that `id` attributes are sharing values when they *must* be unique.

Comment: yes,i think the id is the problem.thank you all

Comment: @ScottMarcus I had a headache while first reading the question... It's much better now when all the fluff that distracts the reader is removed.

Comment: I was creating 3 more radio-buttons,that s all.Not big deal

Comment: @YotamSalmon All that "fluff" is relevant because it shows that the OP is creating sets of radio buttons.

Comment: Ok, ok! Don't crucify me! :-P I just think one example of radio button creation and a comment that 2 more are next would be sufficient and not deter people from looking at the question. Sorry if it came out rude xx

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute must be different for each question:

```
    <form>
    <!-- Question 01 -->
    <fieldset id="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group1">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="group2">
    <!-- Question 02 -->
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening because every "radio button pack" `test_2()` is generating has the same `name` property value (`answ`).
A quick solution would be to send a `name` as a parameter to `test2` so you "namespace" your radiobuttons like this:

```
function test_2(name) {

  var a = getRandom(0, 10) - 5;

  ...

  radio1.setAttribute('name', name + '-answ');

  ...
```

}

This way, if you're calling this function within a loop, you can pass in the index as the name parameter and ensure uniqueness of names.